# javascript promise still executing code synchronously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so basically i have a web application that retrieves data from firebase. and since it takes a lot of time to retrieve data from firebase, i used promise to make my code to populate at the right time. here is my code:

```
var promise = getDataFirebase();
promise.then(function () {
    console.log(Collect);

    console.log("firsst");
    return getDataFirebaseUser();
}).then(function () {

    console.log("Second");

});



function getDataFirebase() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        refReview.on("value", function (snap) {
            var data = snap.val();
            for (var key in data) {


                Collect.push({
                    "RevieweeName": data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
                    "ReviewerName": data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
                    rating: data[key].rating,
                    content: data[key].content,
                    keyOfReviewee: data[key].revieweeID.userID
                })
                var getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(data[key].revieweeID.userID);
                getDataToUsers.once("value", async function (snap) {
                    var fnLn = snap.val();
                    var first = fnLn.isTerminated;
                    console.log("terminateStatus", first);

                });


            }//end of for loop
            resolve();
        }); //end of snap 
    });
}
```

so in function getDataFirebase, data is retrieved from firebase and is push to an array called , Collect. So, after pushing 1 row, it query again to the firebase for another table of data then continues the loop. The problem here is that, i wanted to finish all processes before it resolves the promise.

the output of console according to the code is as follow:

```
 Collect (array)
first
Second
terminateStatus, 1
```

it must be

```
   Collect (array)
 first
terminateStatus,1
second
```

Comment: `php` tag why ?

Comment: oops sorry about that ali.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "finish all processes" before it resolves.  What are these processes?

Comment: hi, by processes i mean when retrieving data from firebase or finish all the processes from the function , getDataFirebase

Comment: So, what's the problem with what you have now?  What does getDataFirebaseUser() do?

Comment: hello sir. i wanted to execute the function at the right time before it resolves the promise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how your code is working but it looks like you're doing the right thing on `refReview.on("value")`: creating a promise before calling Firebase, and then resolving it afterwards. But you're not doing that on `getDataToUsers.once("value")`. There, you're firing the event and not waiting for it to return — the for-loop continues on, and all the callbacks are processed later, but `resolve` is at the end of the for-loop, so it's too late by then.

My guess is that you thought the `async` keyword would cause the for-loop to wait for that job to complete, but actually all it does here is cause the callback to return a promise — which is ignored by the `on` function.

You have a few options, but probably the best will be to use `Promise.all`, which accepts an array of promises and waits for them all to be resolved — but you should probably use [Firebase's Promise API](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) rather than bolting promises onto the event API. So it'll look something like:

```
refReview.once('value')
    .then(snap => Promise.all(snap.val().map(item =>
        firebase.database()
            .ref("users")
            .child(item.revieweeID.userID)
            .once('value')
            .then(snap => {
                console.log('terminated');
            ])
    })));
```

(except with the actual functionality added in, natch)

Comment: yes, so on point sir andrew. but ive been reading the documentation you linked and been trying for hours already but i cant seem to get the right solution for this. :( can you help me?